# 'No input file specified' over a symbolic link

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I do have two sites. As I only have one SSL certificate, I want to use the one with the certificate for accessing the other (say, for admin). I will consider good enough just to be able to access the files like this: `https://site1.dom/site2.dom/`.

So I did `ln /home/site2/www/ /home/site1/www/site2.dom -s` and made sure that `+FollowSymLinks`.

Nevertheless, I get a `No input specified` message when I try to access `https://site1.dom/site2.dom/` or `http://site1.dom/site2.dom/`.

The directories are owned by different unix users. Most (if not all) of the files permissions are `755`.

What's wrong? -I ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `FollowSymLinks` option turned on for the `/home/site2/www/` directory?

Comment: Good point. Now I do, but the same thing is still happening.